# Integrate JavaScript for-loop into custom function

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, ecmascript-6

I have a working EcmaScript-3 function that converts an array into a specific string format.

**Array:**

```
ft: [
    1: {name: "gender", value: "F", focus: 0, type: "radio"}
    2: {name: "firstname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    3: {name: "lastname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    4: {name: "birthday", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    5: {name: "street", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    6: {name: "streetNo", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
]
```

**Specific string format:**

```
ft=gender.radio|F|0;firstName.text|empty|1;lastName.text|empty|0;street.text|empty|0;houseNumber.text|empty|0;zip.text|empty|0;city.text|empty|0;country.select-one|de|0;birthdate-day.text|empty|0;birthdate-month.text|empty|0;birthdate-year.text|empty|0;email.email|empty|0;code.text|filled_out|0
```

**My working function that converts array to specific string format:**

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ft.length; i++) {
    var elem = ft[i];
    arr.push(elem.name + "." + elem.type + "|" + elem.value + "|" + elem.focus);
}
var str = arr.join(";");

console.log(str);
```

**Problem:**

I need a function (in EcmaScript-3 format) that can be called like this:

```
var a = tracking()(ft, false);
console.log(a); 

// the console.log(a) should provide as a result: ft=gender.radio|F|0;firstName.text|...; false;
```

**My solution (not working)**

```
function tracking() {
  return function (ft, submitted) {
     var arr = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < ft.length; i++) {
       var elem = ft[i];
       arr.push(elem.name + "." + elem.type + "|" + elem.value + "|" + 
       elem.focus + "submitted");
     }
     var str = arr.join(";");
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your solutions's inner function is returning nothing. Just return str and it will work. https://jsfiddle.net/goa2z159/ Perhaps you need to work on the final format since it's different, but whatever, start by returning something.

Comment: `return str` and you are done

Comment: @JonasWilms the output is different because he added an "elem.focus + submitted" inside the push. Not sure why, but still........

Comment: Oh right, I guess it should be `+ "|" + submitted`

Comment: euuuuuh according to the result he provided, it's unclear how `firstName.text|empty|1;` came out, since focus is always 0. Also, it's unclear how that "submitted" should be positioned, since it's missing in the original result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have made this over complicated. This can be as simple as this

```
function tracking (ft, submitted) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ft.length; i++) {
    var elem = ft[i];
    arr.push(elem.name + "." + elem.type + "|" + elem.value + "|" + 
    elem.focus + "submitted");
  }
  return arr.join(";");
}
```

And I doubt why you got that submitted param. If you want it to use as variable just remove the quotes while pushing it to array